# ReportLab UTF-8 characters with registered fonts

Tags: encoding, utf-8, fonts, report, reportlab

I'm using ReportLab for pdf generation and I'm having some problem with representing the utf-8 characters. ReportLab contains some registered fonts available but seems like none of them support utf-8.

```
print p.getAvailableFonts()
['Courier', 'Courier-Bold', 'Courier-BoldOblique', 'Courier-Oblique', 'Helvetica', 'Helvetica-Bold', 'Helvetica-BoldOblique', 'Helvetica-Oblique', 'Symbol', 'Times-Bold', 'Times-BoldItalic', 'Times-Italic', 'Times-Roman', 'ZapfDingbats']
```

I checked similar questions about this topic and the general suggestion is using a font which has utf-8 characters in it. But I'm pretty sure "Times-Roman" and "Helvetica" fonts have utf-8 characters like "ş,ı,ğ". But the outcome doesn't seems so.

```
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('Verdana', 'Verdana.ttf'))

p.setFont("Times-Roman", 24)
p.drawCentredString(297,600,"şırküç")
p.setFont("Verdana", 24)
p.drawCentredString(297,550,"şırküç")
p.setFont("Helvetica", 24)
p.drawCentredString(297,500,"şırküç")
```

I register a new font named "Verdana" and it works as expected. But i can't use the available fonts.

[image: utf results]

I want to use "Helvetica" and "Times-Roman" fonts in my document but can't make it working.

Answer (score 2):

PDF standard defines a set of 14 fonts that have to be available in all compliant readers. As I can see, you found them. But all those fonts contain only a limited set of glyphs. It's roughly similar to ISO-8859-1, so no Turkish.

If you can, it's recommended to always embed your own fonts.

So I suggest you embed appropriate fonts of your choice instead of depending on built-in and limited `Times-Roman` and `Helvetica`. From what I can see, those examples you posted look like Times New Roman and Arial respectively, but in order to fully legally embed those two fonts in PDFs, you need a licence. You can use FreeSerif, Nimbus Roman No 9 L, Nimbus Sans L, FreeSans, and Liberation Sans instead if you want to go full legit.

EDIT: Verdana is also proprietary, I don't know what free alternative to suggest.

Of course, if you are not going to distribute those PDF's publicly, you don't have to worry about licences.